# What is the function of 了 in the sentence 我最怕去西单了?

Tags: particles

Received this in a text from a Chinese friend. I want to say that "了" here is not part of the verb phrase but instead just an emphatic particle, same as if you said something like "我最怕蜘蛛了"。Then again, that's not something I would ever think to produce, it just sounds more normal that way to me. Does anyone have a more authoritative answer?

Comment: I thought this was simply used as an exclamation to emphasize a feeling/an emotion. I am not quite sure though.

Answer (score 6):

In a phrase with this construct:

> 可/太/最 + [adjective/adverb/stative verb] + 了

了 serves as a modal article (rather than tense particle) to express emphasis and is optional.

Reference: http://cdmd.cnki.com.cn/Article/CDMD-10475-1012379314.htm

Answer (score 2):

"我最怕蜘蛛了" totally equals "我最怕蜘蛛" from the perspective of grammar and meaning. "了", which is similar to "喔", "吧" and "呀", is an auxiliary word that can be omitted because it doen't have any meaning, but it's very weird to omit it in some situations. Unfortunately, even native speakers can't tell you the exact rule of when to use this auxiliary word.

Generally speaking, you should use it when you are **speaking** and omit it when you are **writing**. Basing on the same logic, you should use it when you are writing someone's talk. for instance, you should write

> 他說：「我最怕蜘蛛了。」

rather than

> 他說：「我最怕蜘蛛。」

However, please remember that it's "general speaking". I am sorry that it's very hard to tell you the exact rule.

Answer (score 1):

As I native speaker, I would say that "了" is mainly used to help with expressing an emotion.

> 我最爱你了
>   I love you the most

where "了" helps express affinity toward someone. Sometimes "了" is also used to express the 'donenness' of an action.

> 我吃完了
>   I have eaten

where "了" helps express perfect tense.

Comment: i don't think "了" in the first sentence "helps express affinity toward someone". it just helps this sentence to be smooth. however, your second example is excellent!